# Maximum Bending Stress

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I was just wondering for this question if you can see anything wrong with it. The answer in the textbook is 220MPa but i get 193MPa

[image][image]

Comment: As a civil/structural engineer I have no idea what a "thrust" or "journal" bearing is. Perhaps one or the other provides some sort of moment restraint?

Comment: You can also use https://forceeffect.autodesk.com/frontend/fe.html for checking your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is 193 MPa as you have written. I have used [SkyCiv Beam](https://skyciv.com/beam-calculator-features) software to confirm this. It's highly unlikely you are both wrong. The shaft is essentially a beam so it's fine to use beam software for this.

[image: SkyCiv Beam used to determine bending stress of shaft]

[image: Bending stress profile in SkyCiv]

Comment: How did you find stress results?

Comment: SkyCiv Beam Software...i said that in my answer

Comment: Well i use sky civ for sfd and bmds. I never saw shear stress calculations

Comment: You have to add a beam section to get stress and deflection results